# how to parse complex data type in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have an input.txt looks like the following:

```
{"zone_id":12,"position":[100,200,300]} 
{"zone_id":14,"position":[101,201,0]}
```

My question is how can I get the output looks like the following:

```
(12, 100, 200, 300)
(14, 101, 201, 0)
```

Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to solve this problem, but I think the simplest one is using [REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/func.html#regex-extract-all).

```
A = LOAD B FROM '...' USING TextLoader() AS (line:chararray);

B = FOREACH A GENERATE
    REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line, '^..zone_id..(\d*)..position..(\d*),(\d*),(\d*)..$');
```

This approach uses [`TextLoader`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/func.html#textloader) to read one line at a time (separated by newlines) into a `chararray`.
Next, the `FOREACH...GENERATE` applies the `REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL`, which pulls each group from within the parenthesis and returns it into a tuple. Now you can do whatever you'd like.

Watch out if your data changes form. If so, you'll have to write a more flexible regex.

If you want to deal with numbers and not strings, you can [cast](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/basic.html#cast) them.

---

I used `REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL` all here because I'm assuming your data is going to be somewhat similar every time. If you want a more robust solution you can look at [`JsonLoader`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/func.html#jsonloadstore). You can map your data to a schema, and then project the nested fields that it returns into columns.

[This seems like a reasonable blog post on the subject.](http://joshualande.com/read-write-json-apache-pig/)

---

Disclaimer: Where I am I can't test this regex, but hopefully you get the idea. Also, I'm being lazy and using dots instead of the specific characters.